# pdf download problem

Tags: browser, mime-types

I just want to add a link for pdf file.

But when i click on the link then pdf file open in the browser,

But i want that user prompt for to save or open the pdf file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add a header in the response from the server:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<your-file-name>"
```